# SQL insert data into a brand new column fails

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I'm using a script like the following, but it keeps complaining of an Invalid column name 'NewColumnA' .  Is dynamic sql necessary to accomplish this, or is there an easier solution?

```
ALTER TABLE TableA ADD NewColumnA VARBINARY(300)

UPDATE TableA
SET 
    NewColumnA=b.OldColumnB,
FROM 
    TableA a, TableB b
WHERE a.myID=b.myID
```

Comment: Is this run from SSMS or from a stored procedure?  If from SSMS, you probably want `GO` between your `ALTER` and `UPDATE` statements to commit the alter first.

Comment: Sorry, it's SSMS; I've added the tag now.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `Go` (which `Signals the end of a batch of Transact-SQL statements`) after `ALTER TABLE`;

```
ALTER TABLE TableA ADD NewColumnA VARBINARY(300)
GO
--rest of the query
UPDATE TableA
SET 
    NewColumnA=b.OldColumnB,
FROM 
    TableA a, TableB b
WHERE a.myID=b.myID
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with a [`GO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx) :

```
ALTER TABLE TableA ADD NewColumnA VARBINARY(300)

GO

UPDATE TableA
SET 
    NewColumnA=b.OldColumnB,
FROM 
    TableA a, TableB b
WHERE a.myID=b.myID
```